# How to route OpenVpn traffic through another server?

Tags: ssh, routing, openvpn

I have a server (ubuntu 22.04) with Openvpn on it on port 443 (with docker image kylemanna/docker-openvpn). It is working with no problem and the clients can connect to it. The problem is that the internet of the server has some limitations so I want to tunnle openvpn traffic through a new server so that the clients have no limitations. I don't want to tell the clients to connect to the new server, I want them to connect to the old one but the traffic goes through the new one. I think it can be done with routing, but I have no idea how to do it. I also can change OpenVpn installation to be directly on the server without using docker images if needed. I have access to the new server too and I can install a VPN on it, or connect to it via SSH.

> Clients ---> Server (with limited internet) ---> New Server (unlimited internet)

Container ports:
[image: container ports]